# How can I stop the macOS firewall from blocking Django server (Python)?

Tags: security, big-sur, python, firewall

For several years I have been regularly using Python's Django framework and running its web server for development purposes on my local machine. I took a break over the past year and am now returning to Django after upgrading my Mac to Big Sur in the interim. However, the firewall is now blocking my Django server and I can't figure out how to fix this.

I have verified that the firewall is indeed the issue. If I try to issue a request to the Django server from another computer on the network, the request will time out if the firewall is active. If I disable the firewall, the same request will succeed.

I have gone into `System Preferences -> Firewall -> Firewall Options`. The python binary from my project's `venv/bin` directory was added to the list in `Firewall Options` and had `Allow Incoming Connections` enabled. I tried removing it from this list as well, in the hopes of forcing a new system prompt to allow incoming connections, but that has not worked and now python is not listed under the `Firewall Options` list of applications. I cannot add it back into the list either.

I'm at a bit of a loss for what to do here. It used to work fine, but since updating my macOS version, something has been changed that is causing the firewall to block incoming connections to the Django server.

Comment: What ports do you want the web server to be able to listen over? Basically you might need to configure the firewall to allow those ports or are you hoping to have python open any arbitrary port and have it signal to the firewall to make a configuration change on the fly?

Comment: It happens to be set up on port 5000 but it need not necessarily be on that port. I should note that I have gotten it working now but it was after updating python, reinstalling virtualenv, creating a new virtualenv, as well as performing various other configuration changes in process. Then, when I ran the server in the new virtualenv, I received the macOS prompt to allow incoming connections for Python. I am not entirely sure which specific parts of that led to the resolution.